# In excel how to extract data from specific character upto next character

Tags: excel, vba

I have a long paragraph of data and I want to extract specific data from using character up to next specific character e.g in trailing paragraph I want to extract Material Value.

```
<div>New</div></td></tr><tr><td class=display-name rowspan=1 
colspan=1>Material</td><td class=value font-semibold rowspan=1 colspan=1>
<div>Plastic</div></td></tr><tr><td class=display-name rowspan=1 
colspan=1>Manufacturer Part Number</td><td class=value font-semibold 
rowspan=1 colspan=1><div>WHL-103-C</div></td></tr><tr><td class=display-name 
rowspan=1 colspan=1>Color</td><td class=value fonSpecifications</h3><div 
title=Specifications class=Specifications><div><div class=Collapsable 
style=overflow: hidden; position: relative; max-height: 430px; max-width: 
none; box-sizing: border-box;><div class=zeus-collapsable clearfix 
style=display: block; box-sizing: border-box;><div><table class=table table-
striped-odd specification><tbody><tr><td class=display-name rowspan=1 
colspan=1>Material</td><td class=value font-semibold rowspan=1 colspan=1>
<div>Paper</div>
```

From above text I want to extract following value i.e i require following output

```
Material</td><td class=value font-semibold rowspan=1 colspan=1><div>Plastic
```

Comment: Are you scraping this from the web?  If so use the elements to get what you want.

Comment: No  i have data in excel and just want extract specific values

Comment: Ok, I'd use `MID` and `INSTR`

Comment: Actully i require excel formula or similar function for above text extaction

Comment: use `SEARCH` instead of `INSTR` like  `=mid(a1,search(a1,"material"....` along those lines.  Look at the help for `MID` which will then show you the start and num chars, which you'll calculate from `SEARCH`

Comment: but i want to extract from material upto these lines and these lines accurance is not first.  </div></td></tr><tr><td class=display-name rowspan=1 colspan=1>

Comment: i.e i just want to search first accournace of after character after material word(</div></td></tr><tr><td class=display-name rowspan=1 colspan=1>)

Comment: Please edit the question and specify what is the exact output you expect.

Comment: @TahirSatti Why dont you search for `material` and print whatever is in the right of it?

Comment: But with materail there are many values and i require only Meterial value